# Validate optional values with Colander

Tags: python, pyramid, colander

I'm using [Colander](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/basics.html#schema-node-objects) to validate request parameters for a Pyramid web server. For example:

```
class MySchema(colander.MappingSchema):                                         
    first_name = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String())                               
    last_name = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String())
```

Here, `first_name` and `last_name` are required parameters. If I use `missing=''` then this would make them optional, but they would still be added to the deserializing as an empty string which isn't really useful if the user submits an empty string.

Best I can think of is `missing=None` and then check for `None` later.

Is there a way to mark a parameter as truly optional? Meaning, if they're not in the request, they shouldn't be in the deserialized result either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for `missing=colander.drop`.
From [docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/api.html#colander.drop):

> colander.drop - Represents a value that will be dropped from the schema
>   if it is missing during deserialization. Passed as a value to the
>   missing keyword argument of SchemaNode.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.